# Maximum value of batchsize allowed for cublasDgetrfBatched() from CUBLAS Library

Tags: cuda, gpu, gpgpu, cublas

Is there any maximum batchsize limitation for `cublasDgetrfBatched()`  from CUBLAS library? I am doing a benchmark problem for comparing timings between CPU and GPU. For a batchsize of 1000 i am getting GPU timing greater than CPU timing. But, for a batchsize of 100, i am getting some speedup over CPU.

I have posted below the code that i used for benchmarking.

`1. main.cpp`

```
/*main.cpp goes below*/
#include<stdio.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <cuda.h>
#include <cuda_runtime.h>
#include <cublas_v2.h>
#include "mathlib_blas.h"

int main(){

double**mat;                         
double**mat_scratch1;
int *ipvt;
double *fVec;
double *fVecSave;
double *fVec_scratch;
double *A;                      
double *B;
double **devPtrA;
double **devPtrB;
double **devPtrA_dev;
double **devPtrB_dev;
double *d_x;
double *x;
int *d_pivot_array ;


int *d_info_array;
int *h_info_array;
int batchsize;
int neqn;

cublasHandle_t handle;
cublasStatus_t status;
cudaError_t error;

clock_t start, end, start1, end1;

double rcond;
batchsize = 32;
neqn = 172;

mat = (double**) ArrayAlloc2d((size_t) neqn, (size_t) neqn, sizeof(double)); 
mat_scratch1 = (double**) ArrayAlloc2d((size_t) neqn, (size_t) neqn, sizeof(double));


ipvt = (int*) calloc((size_t) neqn, sizeof(int));
fVec = (double*) calloc((size_t) neqn, sizeof(double));
fVecSave = (double*) calloc((size_t) neqn, sizeof(double));
fVec_scratch = (double*) calloc((size_t) neqn, sizeof(double));

A = (double*)malloc( neqn*neqn*sizeof(A[0])); 
B = (double*)malloc( neqn*neqn*sizeof(B[0])); 

devPtrA = (double**)malloc(batchsize*sizeof(*devPtrA));
devPtrB = (double**)malloc(batchsize*sizeof(*devPtrB));

for(int b_count =0; b_count<batchsize; b_count++){
cudaMalloc((void **)&devPtrA[b_count], neqn*neqn * sizeof(devPtrA[0][0]));
cudaMalloc((void **)&devPtrB[b_count], batchsize*neqn * sizeof(devPtrB[0][0]));
}

cudaMalloc((void **)&devPtrA_dev,  batchsize*sizeof(*devPtrA));
cudaMalloc((void **)&devPtrB_dev,  batchsize*sizeof(*devPtrB));


cudaMemcpy(devPtrA_dev, devPtrA, batchsize*sizeof(*devPtrA), cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);
cudaMemcpy(devPtrB_dev, devPtrB, batchsize*sizeof(*devPtrB), cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);


cudaMalloc((void **)&d_x, neqn*sizeof(double));
x =(double *)malloc(neqn*sizeof(double));

cudaMalloc((void **)&d_pivot_array, batchsize*neqn*sizeof(int));

cudaMalloc((void **)&d_info_array, batchsize*sizeof(int));

h_info_array =(int*)malloc(batchsize*sizeof(int));

cublasCreate(&handle);

srand(time(NULL));



/* Fill in the CPU and GPU Matrix */
for (int iRow = 0; iRow < neqn; iRow++) {
    double sumCol = 0;
    for (int iColumn = 0; iColumn < neqn; iColumn++) {
        for(int b_count =0; b_count<batchsize; b_count++){
            A[neqn*iColumn + iRow] = rand()%10 ;
            mat[iRow][iColumn] = A[neqn*iColumn + iRow];
        }
        sumCol +=A[neqn*iColumn + iRow];
    }
    fVec[iRow] = sumCol;
    fVecSave[iRow] = sumCol;
}

/*CPU_CODE GOES HERE */

start = clock();
for(int b_count =0; b_count<batchsize; b_count++){ 

     for (int iRow = 0; iRow < neqn; iRow++) {
         for (int iColumn = 0; iColumn < neqn; iColumn++) {
            mat_scratch1[iColumn][iRow]= mat[iColumn][iRow];
         }
     }

     dgeco_blas(mat_scratch1, neqn, ipvt, &rcond, fVecSave);   
     }

      for (int iRow = 0; iRow < neqn; iRow++) {
         for (int iColumn = 0; iColumn < neqn; iColumn++) {
            mat[iColumn][iRow]= mat_scratch1[iColumn][iRow];
         }
     }

    for(int b_count =0; b_count<batchsize; b_count++){ 
  for(int i = 0; i < neqn; i++) fVec_scratch[i] = fVec[i];    
  dgesl_blas(mat, neqn, ipvt , fVec_scratch, 0); 
  }

end = clock();
float seconds = (float)(end - start) / CLOCKS_PER_SEC;

printf("Time in seconds(CPU) : %lf \n", seconds);
/*CPU_CODE ENDS HERE */


start1 = clock();

for(int b_count =0; b_count<batchsize; b_count++){ 
    status = cublasSetMatrix(neqn, neqn, sizeof(A[0]), A, neqn, devPtrA[b_count], neqn);
}

status = cublasDgetrfBatched(handle, neqn, ( double**)devPtrA_dev,neqn,d_pivot_array,d_info_array,batchsize); 
if (status != CUBLAS_STATUS_SUCCESS) fprintf(stderr,"error in dgetrf %i\n",status);

cudaMemcpy(h_info_array, d_info_array, batchsize*sizeof(int), cudaMemcpyDeviceToHost);


for(int b_count =0; b_count<batchsize; b_count++){ 
    cudaMemcpy(devPtrB[b_count], fVec, neqn*sizeof(double),cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);     /* for testing purpose only */
    }

status = cublasDgetrsBatched(handle, CUBLAS_OP_N, neqn, batchsize, (const double**)devPtrA_dev, 
                     neqn, d_pivot_array,devPtrB_dev, neqn, h_info_array, batchsize);                                                                   

for(int b_count =0; b_count<batchsize; b_count++){ 
    cudaMemcpy( fVec,devPtrB[b_count], neqn*sizeof(double),cudaMemcpyDeviceToHost);     /* for testing purpose only */
}


end1 = clock();
float seconds1 = (float)(end1 - start1) / CLOCKS_PER_SEC;

printf("Time in seconds(GPU) : %lf \n", seconds1);

printf("Speedup(CPU/GPU) : %lf \n", seconds/seconds1);

system("pause");
/* End of the main portion of the code */

free(mat);
free(mat_scratch1);
free(ipvt);
free(fVec);
free(fVecSave);
free(fVec_scratch);
free(A);
free(B);
cudaFree(devPtrA[0]);
cudaFree(devPtrB[0]);
cudaFree(devPtrA_dev);
cudaFree(devPtrB_dev);
free(devPtrA);
free(devPtrB);
cudaFree(d_x);
free(x);
cudaFree(d_pivot_array);
cudaFree(d_info_array);
free(h_info_array);
cublasDestroy_v2(handle);


}
```

`2. mathlib_blas.h`

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>

#define maxm(a,b)   (((a) > (b)) ? (a) : (b))
#define minm(a,b)   (((a) < (b)) ? (a) : (b))
#define signum(a,b)   (((b) < (0)) ? (-a) : (a)) 

void **ArrayAlloc2d( const int size1, const int size2, const size_t   sizeType);
void dgefa_blas(double **a,int n, int ipvt[],int *info);
void dgesl_blas(double **a,int n,int ipvt[],double b[],int job);
void dgeco_blas(double **a,int n, int *ipvt, double *rcond,double *z);



void **ArrayAlloc2d( const int size1, const int size2, const size_t sizeType )
 {
  void** array = nullptr;

  array = (void**)calloc(size1, sizeof(void*));

  if (array != nullptr) {
     if (size2 > 0) {
        void* data = calloc(size1*size2, sizeType);

        if (data != nullptr) {
           char* addr = (char*)data;

           for (int index1 = 0; index1 < size1; index1++) {
              array[index1] = (void*)addr;
              addr += sizeType*size2; /* char is always 1 byte */
           }
        } else {

           free(array);
           free(data);
           array = nullptr;


        }
     }
   } else {

   }


    return array;
 }

 void dgeco_blas(double **a,int n, int *ipvt, double *rcond,double *z)
 {
 double anorm,ek,s,sm,t,vecdot,vecsum,wk,wkm,ynorm;
 int i,info,j,k,kb,kp1,l;

 /* Compute 1-norm of a */
 anorm = 0.0;
 for (j = 0; j < n; j++) {
  vecsum = 0.0;
  for (i = 0;i < n; i++)
     vecsum += fabs(a[i][j]);
  anorm = maxm(anorm,vecsum);
 }

 /* Factor. */
 dgefa_blas(a,n,ipvt,&info);   

 /* rcond = 1/(norm(a) * (estimate of norm(inverse(a)))).
 * estimate = norm(z)/norm(y), where a*z=y and trans(a)*y=e.
 * trans(a) is the transpose of a. The components of e are
 * chosen to cause maximum local growth in the elements of
 * w, where trans(u)*w=e. The vectors are frequently rescaled
 * to avoid overflow.
 */
 ek = 1.0;
 for (j = 0; j < n; j++)
  z[j] = 0.0;
  for (k = 0; k < n; k++) {
  if (z[k] != 0.0)
     ek = signum(ek,-z[k]);
  if (fabs(ek-z[k]) > fabs(a[k][k])) {
     s = fabs(a[k][k])/fabs(ek-z[k]);
     /* dscal(n,s,z,1) */
     for (i = 0; i < n; i++)
        z[i] *= s; 
     ek *= s;
  }
  wk = ek - z[k];
  wkm = -ek - z[k];
  s = fabs(wk);
  sm = fabs(wkm);
  if (a[k][k] != 0.0) {
     wk /= a[k][k];
     wkm /= a[k][k];
  }
  else {
     wk = 1.0;
     wkm = 1.0;
  }
  kp1 = k + 1;
  if (kp1 < n) {
     for (j = kp1; j < n; j++) {
        sm += (fabs(z[j] + wkm * a[k][j]));
        z[j] += (wk * a[k][j]);
        s += fabs(z[j]);
     }
     if (s < sm) {
        t = wkm -wk;
        wk = wkm;
        for (j = kp1; j < n; j++)
           z[j] += (t * a[k][j]);
     }
  }
  z[k] = wk;
  }

   /* dasum(n,s,z,1) */
 vecsum = 0.0;

 for (i = 0;i < n; i++)
   vecsum += fabs(z[i]);
 s = 1.0/vecsum;

 /* dscal(n,s,z) */
 for (i = 0; i < n; i++)
  z[i] *= s;

 /* Solve trans(l)*y= w
 */
 for (kb = 0; kb < n; kb++) {
   k = n - kb - 1;
  if (k < (n-1)) {
     /* sdot(n-k,a(k+1,k),1,z(k+1),1) */
     vecdot = 0.0;
     for (i = k+1;i < n; i++)
        vecdot += (a[i][k] * z[i]);
     z[k] += vecdot;
    }
    if (fabs(z[k]) > 1.0) {
     s = 1.0/fabs(z[k]);
     /* dscal(n,s,z) */
     for (i = 0; i < n; i++)
        z[i] *= s;
    }
    l = ipvt[k];
    t = z[l];
    z[l] = z[k];
    z[k] = t;
  } /* endfor kb */
  /* dasum(n,z,1) */
  vecsum = 0.0;
  for (i = 0; i < n; i++)
  vecsum += fabs(z[i]);
  s = 1.0/vecsum;
  /* dscal(n,s,z) */
  for (i = 0; i < n; i++)
  z[i] *= s;   

  ynorm = 1.0; 
  /*
  * Solve l * v = y
  */
  for (k = 0; k < n; k++) {
  l = ipvt[k];
  t = z[l];
  z[l] = z[k];
  z[k] = t;
  if (k < (n-1)) {
     /* daxpy(n-k,t,a[k+1][k],1,z[k+1],1) */
     for (i = k+1;i < n; i++)
        z[i] += (t * a[i][k]);
  }
  if (fabs(z[k]) > 1.0) {
     s = 1.0/fabs(z[k]);
     /* dscal(n,s,z,1) */
     for (i = 0; i < n; i++)
        z[i] *= s;
     ynorm *= s;
   }
  }
  /* dasum(n,z,1) */
  vecsum = 0.0;
  for (i = 0; i < n; i++)
  vecsum += fabs(z[i]);
  s = 1.0/vecsum;
   /* dscal(n,s,z,1) */
  for (i = 0; i < n; i++)
  z[i] *= s;
  ynorm *= s;

  /* Solve u * z = v */
  for (kb = 0; kb < n; kb++) {
  k = n - kb - 1;
  if (fabs(z[k]) > fabs(a[k][k])) {
     s = fabs(a[k][k])/fabs(z[k]);
     /* dscal(n,s,z,1) */
     for (i = 0; i < n; i++)
        z[i] *= s;
     ynorm *= s;
   }
   if (a[k][k] != 0.0)
     z[k] /= a[k][k];
   if (a[k][k] == 0.0)
     z[k] = 1.0;
   t = -z[k];
   /* daxpy(k-1,t,a[1][k],1,z[1],1) */
   for (i = 0; i < k; i++)
     z[i] += (t * a[i][k]);
  }
  /* Make znorm = 1.0 */
  /* dasum(n,z,1) */
  vecsum = 0.0;
  for (i = 0; i < n; i++)
  vecsum += fabs(z[i]); 
  s = 1.0/vecsum;

  /* dscal(n,s,z,1) */
  for (i = 0; i < n; i++)
  z[i] *= s;
  ynorm *= s;

  if (anorm != 0.0) *rcond = ynorm/anorm;
  if (anorm == 0.0) *rcond = 0.0;
  }



  void dgefa_blas(double **a,int n, int ipvt[],int *info)
  {
  double dmax,t;
  int i,j,k,kp1,l,nm1;

 *info = 0;
 nm1 = n - 1;
 if (n > 0) {
  for (k = 0; k < nm1; k++) {
     kp1 = k + 1;
     /* Find l = pivot index. */
     dmax = fabs(a[k][k]);
     l = k;
     for (i = k+1; i < n; i++) {
        if (fabs(a[i][k]) <= dmax) continue;
        l = i;
     }
     ipvt[k] = l;

     /* Zero pivot implies this column already triangularized. */
     if (a[l][k] == 0.0) {
        *info = k;
        continue;
     }

     /* Interchange if necessary. */
     if (l != k) {
        t = a[l][k];
        a[l][k] = a[k][k];
        a[k][k] = t;
     }

     /* Compute multipliers. */
     if (a[k][k] == 0.0) printf("\n!ERROR. Singular matrix.\n");
     t = -1.0/a[k][k];
     for (i = k+1; i < n; i++)
        a[i][k] *= t;

     /* Row elimination with column indexing. */
     for (j = kp1; j < n; j++) {
        t = a[l][j];
        if (l != k) {
           a[l][j] = a[k][j];
           a[k][j] = t;
        }
        for (i = k+1; i < n; i++ )
           a[i][j] += (t * a[i][k]);
     }
    }
   } 
   ipvt[n-1] = n-1;
   if (a[n-1][n-1] == 0.0) *info = n-1;
}



 void dgesl_blas(double **a,int n,int ipvt[],double b[],int job)
{
 double t;
 int i,k,kb,l,nm1;

 nm1 = n - 1;
 if (job == 0) {

  /* job = 0, solve a * x = b.
  * First solve l * y = b.
  */
  if (n > 0) {
     for (k = 0; k < nm1; k++) {
        l = ipvt[k];
        t = b[l];
        if (l != k) {
           b[l] = b[k];
           b[k] = t;
        }
        /* saxpy(n-k,t,a(k+1,k),1,b(k+1),1); */
        for (i=k+1;i < n;i++)
           b[i] += (t * a[i][k]); 
     }
   } 

    /* Now solve u * x = y. */
    for (kb = 0; kb < n; kb++) {
     k = n - kb-1;
     b[k] /= a[k][k];
     t = -b[k];
     /*      saxpy(k-1,t,a(1,k),1,b(1),1); */
     for (i = 0; i < k ; i++)
        b[i] += (t * a[i][k]);
    }
    return;
  }
  /* job != 0, solve trans(a) * x = b.
 * First solve trans(u) * x = y.
 */
 for (k = 0; k < n; k++) {
  /*  t = ddot(k-1,a(1,k),1,b(1),1); */
  t = 0;
  for (i = 0; i < k; i++)
     t += (a[i][k] * b[i]);
  b[k] = (b[k] - t)/a[k][k];
 }

 /* Now solve trans(l) * x = y. */

 if (n > 0) {
  for (kb = 0; kb < nm1; kb++) {
     k = n - 2 - kb;
     /* b[k] = b[k] + ddot(n-k,a(k+1,k),1,b(k+1),1); */
     t = 0;

     for (i = k+1;i < n; i++)
        t += (a[i][k] * b[i]);
     b[k] += t;
     l = ipvt[k];

     if (l != k) {
        t = b[l];
        b[l] = b[k];
        b[k] = t;
     }
    } 
  }
}
```

Comment: "GPU timings greater than CPU timings" means GPU is slower? anyway, you should post the bechmark code you use as a [mcve].

Comment: I have uploaded the gpu version of the code [here](https://www.dropbox.com/s/4yndy95o6u5wqor/main.cpp?dl=0)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There should not be any behavioral differences between a batch size of 100 and a batch size of 1000.  (Certainly there would be a performance difference - the batch size of 1000 should probably take longer.)

There are no [published limits to the batch size](http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cublas/index.html#cublas-lt-t-gt-getrfbatched), other than implicit memory limits.   In fact, unless the GPU is returning incorrect results, there is no reason to think that you've run into any hard limit anyway.

( If you wanted to explore some behavioral or performance issue, this question is not properly written to address that. )

Comment: I have uploaded the GPU version of the code [here](https://www.dropbox.com/s/4yndy95o6u5wqor/main.cpp?dl=0)

Comment: (1) From the posted code it is not clear what is being timed, and how. (2) The speed of a solver depends somewhat on the data, as partial pivoting is likely used. By using different random data for every run measurements are likely to be non-repeatable.

Comment: and there is no comparison to a CPU version

Comment: I have uploaded the revised version of code [here](https://www.dropbox.com/s/4yndy95o6u5wqor/main.cpp?dl=0) and [here](https://www.dropbox.com/s/6eu7e7e9nt9bhvn/mathlib_blas.h?dl=0) which has comparison of timing between CPU and GPU for a single batchsize. I ran the code with 8 different batchsize. The speed up for batchsizes of 1, 10, 64, 100, 200, 300, 500, 1000 were found to be   1.80x, 13.28x,  29.5x, 24.91x, 17.89x, 13.28x, 8.58x, and  4.76x respectively. The speedup is maximum around batchsize of 64. Any reason behind the decrease of speedup with the increase in batchsize after 64?

Comment: Sorry, at this time I don't have access to dropbox.  Why not post your code in the question?  SO expects that you post the code in the question, not in an external link.

Comment: First, I'm not sure your GPU and CPU codes are doing the same thing.  Second, your question was about `cublasDgetrfBatched()`.  If I comment out the call to `cublasDgetrsBatched` in your code, and the `cudaMemcpy` operations right before it and right after it, then I observe a fairly constant speedup factor CPU to GPU.  In other words, the performance of `cublasDgetrfBatched()` seems to be fairly linear with batchsize, which is pretty much what I would expect.